# Why is addEventListener increment code not working?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning and I like to know why certain codes happen the way they do. So, created a code to increment by 1 when a button is clicked and have that displayed on the screen. However, when using addEventListener, it didnt work. It only added 1 and never increased by 1 again.

But when I used onclick Event in html, it worked fine and incremented. What could be the issue? Here are the codes:

HTML

```
<div class="score container">
<h3 class="firstScore">0</h3>
<h3 class="to">To</h3>
<h3 class="secondScore">0</h3>
```

Player One

JS code with addEventLister. This doesnt increment, But when I used consol.log(count), it increased by 1 but grayed out. Kindly check the attached screenshot
[image: screen shot of my console]

```
var playerOne = document.querySelector('.playerOne')

playerOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count = 0;

  function countNum() {
    count++;
    document.querySelector('.firstScore').innerHTML = count;
  }
  countNum()
})
```

This is the JS code that I used onclick and added the function to the button directly. This is working fine. I want to know what made the addEventListener not to work?

```
count = 0;

function countNum() {
  count++;
  document.querySelector('.firstScore').innerHTML = count;
  console.log(count)
}
```

The button with the html:

```
<button onclick="countNum()"  class="playerOne">Player One</button>
```

Comment: Every time the function is called, it initializes `count` to `0`.

Comment: "*what made the addEventListener not to work?*" - you placed *all* the code in the handler, not just the `countNum()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your `var count = 0` outside from `addEventListener` function. Otherwise on each `click` you will reset your counter and then immediately increment it, which means you always assign to `innerHTML` value equal to `1`.

Fixed example with `addEventListener`:

```js
var playerOne = document.querySelector('.playerOne');
var firstScore = document.querySelector('.firstScore');
var count = 0;
var countNum = function() {
  count++;
  firstScore.innerHTML = count;
};

playerOne.addEventListener('click', countNum);
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/crk1x6ya/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is good to ask questions. Now, I understand better and will avoid such mistake. Your explanation makes sense to me more.

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `count` to `0` every time the function is called.

You need to use the inner function as the event listener, not the outer function. You can do this with an IIFE that returns the inner function.

```js
var playerOne = document.querySelector('.playerOne')

playerOne.addEventListener('click', (() => {
  count = 0;

  function countNum() {
    count++;
    document.querySelector('.firstScore').innerHTML = count;
  }
  return countNum;
})())
```

```html
<div class="score container">
<h3 class="firstScore">0</h3>
<h3 class="to">To</h3>
<h3 class="secondScore">0</h3>
<button class="playerOne">Player One</button>
```

Comment: Okay..thanks. But why did the onclick version worked? I'm really sorry if I'm asking stupid question.

Comment: Because you don't assign `count = 0;` in the `countNum()` function.

Comment: Yea, now I understand better. Thank you very much.